# RTK query Type `string` is not assignable to type `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rtk-query

I am trying to get benefit of the caching of the rtk query
so when i add an address it auto updates the addresses

but i am getting Type `string` is not assignable to type `undefined`
here is my code

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { IAddress } from '../../../pages/UserProfile/components/Sections/Addresses';

interface GetMyInfoResponse {
  data: { addresses: IAddress[] };
  message: string;
  statusCode: number;
}

interface AddAddressResponse {
  data: { address: IAddress };
  message: string;
  statusCode: number;
}

export const addressApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'addressApi',
  tagTypes: ['address'],
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/address',
    prepareHeaders: (headers: Headers) => {
      const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '{}');
      if (token) headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token.accessToken}`);
      return headers;
    },
  }),

  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getAddresses: builder.query<GetMyInfoResponse, void>({
      query: () => ({ url: `/` }),
      providesTags: ['address'],
    }),
    addAddress: builder.mutation<AddAddressResponse, IAddress>({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: `/`,
        method: 'POST',
        body,
      }),
      providesTags: ['address'],//Type `string` is not assignable to type `undefined`
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetAddressesQuery, useAddAddressMutation } = addressApi;
```

Comment: you can not provide tags to a mutation operation, want you want is `invalidatesTags`

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to use invalidatesTags